# useStates are not updating in React JS

Tags: reactjs

The values of the `useState` are not getting updated, please provide me a solution for this.

Even though I use `UpdateRUInfo(recorderinfo),Updatemi5(mi5module),Updateb5(ebmcard),Updateeth(ethsrc)` at the end, the values are not getting reflected.

So how could this be resolved for the values to get updated. Is there any problem with the structure of the code.

Answer (score 0):

React uses object references to determine if state has been updated. Since you are not creating new objects, but mutating them and keeping the same references, React will not update.

Instead do something like:

```
Updatemi5([{...mi5module, data: whatever}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You Cannot set the state value, the way you are setting

you can use the following way.

```
updateRUInfo([{...recorderinfo, totaldatarate:dateRate}])
```

Comment: what about the sensorstatus?

Comment: Same like others                                                                  
    updateRUInfo([{...recorderinfo, totaldatarate:dateRate, sensorstatus: sensorstatus }])